# Add Members to group in azure active directory using Graph API gives URl invalid error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to add members to the group in Azure Active directory using Graph API's in C# but when I run the code I am getting the below error:

> ServiceException: Code: BadRequest
> Message: Invalid URL format
> specified in @odata.bind for members

Below is my code:

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { Constants.GroupMemberReadWriteAll, Constants.DirectoryReadAsUser })]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddMembersToGroup()
{
    MSGraphs.GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient(new[] { Constants.GroupMemberReadWriteAll, Constants.DirectoryReadAsUser });

            var group = new MSGraphs.Group
            {
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"members@odata.bind", "[\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/c6e5c868-e2bd-46b0-b5f3-c39b5dfe42dc\",\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/b2fc878b-a455-4315-b9e1-8594cbad3404\",\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/79f06743-3bee-418e-8f4e-b381ebdfafc2\"]"}
                }
            };

            await graphClient.Groups["{29f7e645-8de1-45fc-80a5-e76e0fa51340}"]
                .Request()
                .UpdateAsync(group);

            return Ok();
        }
```

Let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of supplying the members as a string (and by that anticipating JSON serialization), you could use a string array:

```
var group = new MSGraphs.Group
  {
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
      {
         { 
            "members@odata.bind", 
            new string[] 
            { 
              "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/c6e5c868-e2bd-46b0-b5f3-c39b5dfe42dc",
              "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/b2fc878b-a455-4315-b9e1-8594cbad3404",
              "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/79f06743-3bee-418e-8f4e-b381ebdfafc2" 
            }
         }
     }
  };
```

This way, .NET can take care of the serialization afterwards.